# redirect after sending mail

Tags: php, laravel

am in need of assistance , its funny but my code is not redirecting after using my contact page , even when i have my return redirect code there

> return redirect('/home');

my contact form works fine, just to redirect ,am using laravel 7

```
public function saveContact(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required|min:5',
            'phone_number' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required|min:10'
        ]);

        $contact = new Contact;

        $contact->name = $request->name;
        $contact->email = $request->email;
        $contact->subject = $request->subject;
        $contact->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
        $contact->message = $request->message;

        $contact->save();

        Mail::send('layouts.email', array(
                 'name' => $request->get('name'),
                 'email' => $request->get('email'),
                 'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
                 'phone_number' => $request->get('phone_number'),
                 'user_message' => $request->get('message'),
             ),  function($message) use ($request)
               {
                  $message->from($request->email);
                  $message->to('thomsontochi@gmail.com');
                  $message->subject('Fidmax');
               });

         Session::flash('success','Thanks for contacting us!');
         return redirect('/home');
```

please help thanks

Comment: Do you have a `\home` URI? Or it is `return redirect('/');`?

Comment: i have a /home route

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:
`return redirect()->route('home')->withSuccess('Thanks for contacting us!');`
or like this:
`return redirect()->route('home')->with('success','Thanks for contacting us!');`?

Comment: this is wierd but i hva tried it, i just dont understand anymore

Comment: gave up , its annoying real, it not just redirecting